# Need tips: ReactJS front-end and Springboot API deployment strategies

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I just want to know how do you guys do it.

Here is what I did:

- I created ReactJs and Springboot API separately.
- In dev environment, I am running ReactJS with npm start and the Springboot just run the Application.
- Access reactJs with : http://localhost:3000
- Access springboot api from react with : http://localhost:8080 using axios
- Since the request from reactJs is technically to a different server (different server and different port): I encountered the CORS problem: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
- So I added @CrossOrigin(origins ="*") on my api.
- Everything is rainbows and butterflies.

And then I deployed to prod environment:

- Server is Ubuntu.
- ReactJs deployed to NGINX
- the Springboot API I just made the jar a service.

First problem that I encountered is I forgot to replace the React's API request with the actual IP address of my server (http://12.34.56.789:8080 instead of http://localhost:8080). So I guess my first question is, how do I dynamically set this API request in react so that when in dev environment it will be: http://localhost:8080 and when in prod env, set it to the ip address.

Second question is, do you normally deploy ReactJs and Springboot API like this? Separately, and Springboot just running its own Applilcation Server through jar.

Third is, what can you suggest I do to improve this setup?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is react running on node because you're using server-side rendering or is it just to do dynamic module replacement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to handle your swapping in and out of the constants :

```
var API = {
    production: JSON.stringify('prod-url'),
    development: JSON.stringify('dev-url')
}

var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

// webpack config
module.exports = {
    // define plugin can handle your constants
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'API_URL': API_URL[environment]
        })
    ],
    // ...
}
```

In your component then

```
    axios(API_URL).then(()=>{

});
```